# Auto-replacing words with shorter variants to prevent hanging words

Tags: line-breaking, wrap

Is there a way to tell latex that certain words can be replaced by a shorter variant if it will prevent a hanging word:

eg:

```
this line wraps to a second
line.
```

change "second" to "2nd" to produce

```
this line wraps to a 2nd line.
```

but the next example wouldn't gain a benefit, so leave it with the longer version:

```
this line is longer and wraps to
a second line, so don't change it.
```

Ideally I'd like to supply a list of words and their variants for the whole document rather than case-by-case, similar to the way you can tell latex to hyphenate words.

Comment: basically no you can not do this, all macro expansion happens before any line breaking in the paragraph is considered, and tex (other than luatex) can not break apart the horizontal list of characters

Comment: Oh well, I've got a lot of individual documents, I'll have to do it manually. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

basically no you can not do this, all macro expansion happens before any line breaking in the paragraph is considered, and tex (other than luatex) can not break apart the horizontal list of characters